# Increase padding above menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

Good afternoon,

I am looking to do two things: 1) increase the padding above my menu. 2) center my menu on the page.

Unfortunately I am a beginner and don't know the code required to perform these functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot:
https://flic.kr/p/omS63R

Webpage:http://visualicreative.com/employee-of-the-month-videos/

Here are the additional pieces of code that I currently use on this template:

```
#thumbnails .controls  { display:  none !important; }

.page-template-template-fullsize-php #main {
max-width: none !important;
}

#primary { box-shadow: none; border: 0 none; }

.page-template-template-fullsize-php #main { margin-top: 0; }

.page-template-template-fullsize-php #header { margin-bottom: 0; }

#welcomeTeaser  { text-transform: none !important; }

.page-template-template-fullsize-php #content .entry-header {
display:none;
}

.page-template-template-fullsize-php #content {
padding: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
} 

#main {padding-top:50px !important;
}
```

Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `#mega-main-menu > .menu_holder` needs more padding, try this for CSS:

```
#mega_main_menu > .menu_holder {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

As far as centering your menu, you need to change the `.not-fixed #site-title, .not-fixed #navigation`:

```
.not-fixed #site-title, .not-fixed #navigation {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 900px;
}
```

Set max-width to anything you like.

Comment: Holy smokes that was fast @mannfromreno. Thank you!

I tried your code in both my template CSS forms and the plugin CSS forms and neither of them worked..

And mhm, it looks like my menu hangs to the left. Weird.

Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: I see what you're saying, I've edited my answer to reflect the centering issue.

Comment: @Jeffrey9896 don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: @mannfromreno 

Thanks for the updated code. Unfortauntely I still can't get them to take affect. Just to double check, where should I be inputting this code. Into my theme CSS style editor or the CSS style editor for mega Menu (the plugin)?

Greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post in your original question any section of code that is affecting this area. It's very difficult to know where to put this code without some context. Thanks.

Comment: @MannfromReno I made your suggested edits above. Thanks for helping me through this problem.